# Add VBA Conditional Statement to Loop

Tags: vba, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements

So I have this code below that currently works. All of the data is on a tab called "Table" and feed into a tab called "Att A" that gets produced into 100+ pdf files and named based on the value that is in column A in the "Table" tab.

I would like to add a conditional statement to the following code that checks the value in column CH in the "Table" tab and if it is greater than 0 save in one location, if it equals 0 then save in another location. Since there are 100+ lines of data, the value in column A needs to check the value in the same row for column CH.

So the logic goes to column A (Uses this value as the file name), creates a file, and checks column CH to determine which folder to save the file in. How do I add this condition to the following code?

```
Sub Generate_PDF_Files()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Table").Activate
    Range("A7").Activate

    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = "STOP"
        X = ActiveCell.Value
        Range("DLR_NUM") = "'" & X

        Sheets("Att A").Select
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "L:\Mike89\Sales" & X & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

        Sheets("Table").Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your code works, we would typically suggest you post it on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), however you're also looking for some help on a conditional statement.

So a few quick things...

- Avoid Select and Activate
- Use Descriptive Variable Naming
- Always Define and Set References to Worksheets and Workbooks
- Never Assume the Worksheet

The conditional itself is very straightforward as shown in the example below, which also incorporates the ideas shared in the links above:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Generate_PDF_Files()
    Dim tableWS As Worksheet
    Dim attaWS As Worksheet
    Dim filename As Range
    Dim checkValue As Range
    Dim filepath As String
    Const ROOT_FOLDER1 = "L:\Mike89\Sales"
    Const ROOT_FOLDER2 = "L:\Mike99\Sales"

    Set tableWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table")
    Set attaWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Att A")
    Set filename = tableWS.Range("A7")
    Set checkValue = tableWS.Range("CH7")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim dlrNum as Range
    set dlrNum = tableWS.Range("DLR_NUM")

    Do Until filename = "STOP"
        dlrNum = "'" & filename
        If checkValue > 0 Then
            filepath = ROOT_FOLDER1 & filename
        Else
            filepath = ROOT_FOLDER2 & filename
        End If
        attaWS.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                                   filename:=filepath, _
                                   Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                                   IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                                   IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                                   OpenAfterPublish:=False
        Set filename = filename.Offset(1, 0)
        Set checkValue = checkValue.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You are awesome!! Thank you. However, it's saving the file in one location and only adjusting the file name to include "Violation" or "No Violation". How do I get it so that is not included in the file name and instead goes into folder named "Violations" and "No Violations"

Comment: You can either change the `ROOT_FOLDER` constants to include the proper destination folder, or change the code where it's building the `filepath`. That's your choice as the developer.

Comment: Changed the file path, but all of the files are creating the same output. So it's naming the files by the list using column A, but not changing "Att A" content to coincide with those values. How do I incorporate this loop?

Comment: As far as I can tell, my example loop produces the same content on "Att A" as your original code. So from your code, there is no indication of how the data should change with each loop in order get different output. That sounds like a different question that your original post. So my suggestion is to step through the code you have and examine your values for the expected change, then modify your code to find the changed data. If you need more help, open up a new SO question and I (or someone else) can directly answer that question.

Comment: Range("DLR_NUM") = "'" & X was not picked up in the new code. I think this is the missing piece since tab "Att A" uses this drop down list to create the content

Comment: Good enough. You should identify which worksheet that range is associated with, as in `attaWS.Range("DLR_NUM")` or `tableWS.Range("DLR_NUM")`. Even better, create a separate `Range` variable and just make that assignment each time to that variable. It's very unclear in your original code why that assignment is being made.

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment regarding a range. Drop-down list "DLR_NUM" feed into a cell in "Att A" that then updates the rest of the content for this tab. Would a range work the same as a loop? The file name and save location you provided are working great, but the content is currently anchored on 1 value in my list DLR_NUM. DLR_NUM refers to A7:A200, so when I create the attachment it should coincise with the value in A

Comment: Your use of the DLR_NUM range in your OP was not clear, especially since it changes the data content of the worksheet. I added a quick definition of the range and set it within the loop - this should work like your original logic.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks! I'll have to read your notes over a couple of more times to make sure I understand the logic. In the early stages of learning VBA.